# Load files that aren't within the Elements or View folders?

Tags: cakephp

Hi I'm trying to make something like CMS with widgets so I have a folder widgets in my app folder there are my widgets for example app/Widgets/UsersOnline/UserOnline.php
I loading them from db with widgets model in beforefilter method in appController and there i pass them to the view, so with a widget helper I would like to render them on the position. But i can't get to the folder widgets/UserOnline/view.ctp with view->element() method this method require file to be in Elements/.

**TLDR / Actual Question:**

Is there any way to load files in view outside the view/ and /elements ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use relative paths when calling the element:

```
<?php echo $this->Element('../../Widgets/UsersOnline/UserOnline'); ?>
```

Don't forget to name your element file 'UserOnline.ctp' too.

Comment: Worth noting these can be absolute too. For example: `APP .DS. 'Path' .DS. 'to' .DS. 'element'` (note the core `APP` constant is an absolute path).