# CakePHP: effectively grouping Elements by the Controller/action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, directory-structure

I'm using [Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) a lot and I've just realised that I started prefixing their filenames with a controller and/or action names.

That made me think that keeping all elements in one folder might feel ok if there's a few of them and they're not controller-specific. Like a header menu, or a dialog of some sort. Otherwise I start feeling like I should group them, and doing that by their names will result in a mess and it just feels wrong.

So I'm thinking about grouping them into folders. The first folder structure that came to mind was `View\ControllerName\Elements\element_name.ctp`, i.e. a specific Elements subfolder in each of the controller folders, but I feel like it would be tricky to include them without [using the full or relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12265889/722036).

Another option would be `View\Elements\ControllerName\element_name.ctp`, i.e. keep the Elements folder and create group them all by controller inside of it. But in that case I'd be duplicating each Controller name in both Elements folder and the View folder itself, meaning that if I ever need to change it I'll have to do that twice. In the first approach the subfolder name name ("Elements") will never change. I know it doesn't really sound like a huge problem as I won't be changing the controller names every day, but the whole approach just sounds not-so-effective because of that.

Do you guys know what would be a better way to do this? 
Please advise

Comment: `Another option would be View\Elements\ControllerName\element_name.ctp` - that's the only option that'll work out of the box. A subtle difference - as described your elements display _model_ data - it would be the model name, not the controller name (even though that are usually the same, the distinction is how you think about wht you're doing e.g. `View\Elements\Posts\summary.ctp` <- display a post (entity) summary. Apart from seeking approval, I'm not sure what the question really is.

Comment: @AD7six I was looking for advice and provided my ideas to show that I invested some thought into this myself. I agree it might sound like I'm looking for approval though. Thanks for pointing out Model vs. Controller name issue, that is a good point